# After removing sddm and lubuntu-desktop, my desktop environment is missing some environment variables

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-environments, environment-variables, paths, xdg

After removing sddm and lubuntu-desktop, and using startx to spin up a graphical interface with my window manager of choice (cwm), `~/.local/bin` is not on the PATH anymore. I googled around and it seems that this path standard is defined by systemd and if you run `systemd-path`, you can see that it expects `~/.local/bin` to be on user's path.

What is the standard, desktop-environment-agnostic way to ensure I have the proper environment variables?

Edit to provide more context: I'm using Lubuntu version 19.04, and the default bash shell.

Comment: @DKBose it's there; however, it doesn't seem to get sourced automatically. I wonder how did sddm or lubuntu-desktop do this.

Comment: I'm not too sure, but "complete" desktop environments may have some sort of session manager taking care of such things.

Comment: When I was using pure Openbox, I had my own autostart file that took care of certain things. Does `cwm` provide a login option in `/usr/share/xsessions`?

Comment: @DKBose yes, it provides a `.desktop` file in `xsessions`.

Comment: In that case, if you had a graphical login screen such as that provided by *sddm*, you could have chosen the cwm session and things might have been handled appropriately? Just guessing!

Comment: @DKBose, possibly, but I find `startx` more ergnomic. I suppose I'll just source `~/.profile` on login.